# Getting VLC to output 5.1 audio

Tags: audio, vlc-media-player, sound-card

I have an Asus Xonar DG sound card in my computer, with a high end 5.1 speaker system. I would like to be able to play movies on this computer, and if they have 5.1 audio, play them using my surround sound system. Unfortulately, This is not something I've been able to figure out how to configure.

I have no idea weather or not it's VLCs fault or my sound cards fault. Given that my sound card hardly works with my computer, I wouldnt be surprised it that was the cause of the problem, but at the same time, other applications such as Adobe premiere and Cubase do output in 5.1, so I have no idea.

I've changed VLC's settings so that it outputs in 5.1 through my sound card, but it doesn't sound any different than when I keep it on automatic; I get my rear, front, and sub channels, but no center... Or at least... I Don't think i can hear anything from the center speaker. You see, when watching a film in 5.1, I can't hear any voices, just, everything but the voices. When I change my sound card to 4 speaker output mode, suddenly I hear the voices again, but the same audio goes through all of my speakers, defeating the purpose of having a 5.1 speaker system.

Does anyone know why VLC just won't output in full 5.1, or for that matter, why my sound card won't let me output VLC audio in 5.1? Thanks!

Comment: You can google for test files that will confirm whether VLC can do 5.1 out of your speakers.  That would be a good first step: http://www.mysurround.com/test/TestMySurround-en.dbr.ac3

Comment: VLC has no problem with 5.1 - so I'd look at your card/drivers/output choice. Don't expect any form of stereo output to be correctly decoded at your 5.1 amp. I use analog 5.1 discrete outputs to mine; saves double-decoding… Even though my amp would be better at it, S/PDIF is not a great idea for 5.1 that's already been decoded in the computer, only to be squeezed back down what was designed as only a stereo pipe.

Comment: @Paul thanks for that. Again, I heard nothing from the center channel, but after purchasing a new external sound device, I can. I Finally had it with that damn Asus card.

Comment: @Tetsujin Yeah, I'm not using S/PDIF. I had individual cables for each channel... and I've tried S/PDIF as well with no luck whatsoever. I broke down and bought a new sound device and now the 5.1 works fine. Didn't change any of VLCs settings so clearly It was a problem with my old sound card...

Comment: Glad you managed to fix it - happy listening :)